# Files deleted but not subfolders

Tags: powershell

Need to purge out the contents of a folder, forcing everything to get cleaned out.
Hmm, why would the subfolders not be removed from within testdir1?

```
$pathvar = "D:\temp\testdir1"
Get-ChildItem -Path $pathvar -Include *.* -File -Recurse | foreach { $_.Delete()}
```

Comment: `-File` only returns files. You must remove that parameter if you want to return files and directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AdminOfThings is correct. `-File` only grabs file just as `-Directory` only grabs folders. Not specifying one of them will grab files and folders.